# Matrix control in text mining

Tags: r, matrix, bigdata, text-mining, tm

I am working on a large dataset of a conference papers. I am planning to perform text mining and topic modeling on this dataset. The dataset contains seven columns of information (including abstract) for 35,451 papers.

```
names(compen)
[1] "Year.the.Paper.was.Presented" "Paper.Title"                 
[3] "Paper.Abstract"               "Author.Name"                 
[5] "Author.s.Organization"        "Reviewing.Committee.s.Code"  
[7] "Reviewing.Committee.s.Name" 
dim(compen)
[1] 35451     7
```

Here's my following code for text mining (works perfectly fine).

```
library(tm)
mydata.corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(compen$Paper.Abstract))
mydata.corpus <- tm_map(mydata.corpus, tolower) 
mydata.corpus <- tm_map(mydata.corpus, removePunctuation, preserve_intra_word_dashes=TRUE)
my_stopwords <- c(stopwords('german'),"the", "due", "are", "not", "for", "this", "and",  "that", "there", "beyond", "time", "from", "been", "both", "than", "has","now", "until", "all", "use", "two", "based", "between", "can",   "different", "each", "have", "however", "its", "level", "more", "most","new", "number","one","other", "paper", "pavement", "such", "their", "these", "used", "using", "were", "when", "which", "with")
mydata.corpus <- tm_map(mydata.corpus, removeWords, my_stopwords)
mydata.corpus <- tm_map(mydata.corpus, removeNumbers)
mydata.dtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(mydata.corpus)
mydata.dtm
dim(mydata.dtm)
findFreqTerms(mydata.dtm, lowfreq=5000)
```

Problem starts from here.

```
term.freq <- rowSums(as.matrix(mydata.dtm))
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 7.7 Gb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In vector(typeof(x$v), nr * nc) :
  Reached total allocation of 8139Mb: see help(memory.size)
2: In vector(typeof(x$v), nr * nc) :
  Reached total allocation of 8139Mb: see help(memory.size)
3: In vector(typeof(x$v), nr * nc) :
  Reached total allocation of 8139Mb: see help(memory.size)
4: In vector(typeof(x$v), nr * nc) :
  Reached total allocation of 8139Mb: see help(memory.size)
```

It surely looks like a memory problem. I am wondering whether there is a way to control the matrix so that memory issue will not rise.

Comment: Are you running 32 bit or 64 bit R?.  Use `Sys.getenv("R_ARCH")` to find out.

Comment: @Borealis your code produces an empty character string to me.

Comment: The cross-platform version is: `.Machine$sizeof.pointer`. An output value of 8 indicates you are running 64 bit.

Comment: It's a 64 bit machine.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a lot of data, but it sounds like the way you are loading it is running out of memory on an 8GB system.  But please try this:

```
require(quanteda)
mydata.corpus <- corpus(compen$Paper.Abstract, 
                        dovcars = compen[-which(names(compen)=="Paper.Abstract")])
mydata.dtm <- dfm(mydata.corpus, ignoredFeatures = my_stopwords)
mydata.dtm
topfeatures(mydata.dfm, 5000)
```

At the moment it does not preserve intra-word hyphens but we will probably add that as an option shortly.  I'd be happy to help you further if you want to use **quanteda** for your problem.  It works well with document-level metadata ("docvars") and can pass off the "dfm" directly to all of the major topic modelling packages -- see `help(convert, package = "quanteda")`.